# What does "batch size" exactly mean in case of AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I read about batch size of getting events from triggers into AWS Lambda, over here: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/serverless-architectures-lambda/batch-size.html)

If the batch size is set to a 10 (say), then does it mean that lambda will wait until there are 10 messages available to process or is it the upper limit - i.e. when fetching events to process, it'll fetch up to 10 at a time?

If 10 events are fetched to process, then how will they be provided as input to the lambda? Will they be provided as an array of 10 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch size is an [upper limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html):

> The number of items in the event **can be smaller than the batch size** if there aren't enough items available, or if the batch is too large to send in one event and has to be split up.

Yes, as an array. For example, [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) of such an event is shown for SQS.